# Why can't I see an error when I let an lvalue reference constructor accept an rvalue in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, value-categories

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
public:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) { cout << "Point()" << endl; }
    Point(Point& p) : x(p.x), y(p.y) { cout << "Point&" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Point p2 = Point(1, 2);  // no error.

    cout << "---" << endl;

    cout << is_copy_constructible<Point>::value << endl;           // 0
    cout << is_trivially_copy_constructible<Point>::value << endl; // 0
    cout << is_move_constructible<Point>::value << endl;           // 0
    cout << is_trivially_move_constructible<Point>::value << endl; // 0
}
```

I think that the `Point` object doesn't have any constructors that accept rvalue arguments, but when I compiled this code on Visual Studio, I couldn't see an error.

Instead, when I compiled this code with g++ compiler, I saw an error as below shown:

```
 cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Point&' to an rvalue of
 type 'Point'
   29 |     Point p3 = Point(2, 3);
      |                ^~~~~~~

constructor_with_lvalue_ref.cpp:16:18: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Point::Point(Point&)' 
   16 |     Point(Point& p) : x(p.x), y(p.y) { cout << "Point&" << endl; }  
      |           ~~~~~~~^
```

I don't understand why I can't see an error on Visual Studio when I let an lvalue reference constructor accept an rvalue.

Can I make the Microsoft compiler make an error with this code?

Comment: Since C++17 this is __Copy initialization__ - _"..First, if T is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as T, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see copy elision..._"_ see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization  Check the language standard flags for the compilers you are testing.

Comment: If you are using MSVC in C++14 mode you should get an error if you add the compiler option `/permissive-`

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you so much! Your answer helped a lot!